# Symfony2 base64 in Entity to File in Form (and inverse) using DataTransformer

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I got a blog plateform, with an entity `Category` this entity has associated to it

- a name
- an icon (small 40*40 png)

as the file is very small and mime-type assured to be always png, I've decided to store the file content as a Base64 encoded string in the entity/database

this way the page can be rendered at once without needing to do extra request for very small files (same for the API call `GET /api/categories` ). for pre-loaded data it works pretty well. The problem come when I want to edit one category

I've created a form with a file type for the icon

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $transformer = new FileToBase64Transformer();

    $iconField = $builder->create('iconColor', 'file', ['required' => false]);
    $iconField->addModelTransformer($transformer);

    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add($iconField)
    ;
}
```

the data transformer being

```
class FileToBase64Transformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($base64)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public function reverseTransform($file)
    {
        if (is_null($file)) {
            return null;
        }

        return base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
    }
}
```

but when i submit the form with a valid image, the form fails
in the profiler, in form section i can see

`Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.icon = THE_BASE_64_OF_THE_FILE`

is it because the data is transformed before the validation happpens ?

- how to modify this code to make it pass the validation
- something i need to wrap my head around is what is going to happen when i will edit if the user upload no new image, how can the image be preserved ?

Comment: Why not a BLOB as database field?

Comment: @Paziツ  the initial idea was to avoid reconverting into base64 every single time (especially as the API call are going to be counted in hundred of thousand before one update happen), but i'm currently considering that path

Comment: @Paziツ  actually it does not change that many things, it just remove the call to base64_encode , but the transformation still need to occur (from File object to a "blob" ) no ?

Comment: I thought with blob thete would be no need ^^ I think you should handlr this in prePersist/preUpdate events of the entity like in normal file uploads

Comment: It's a long shot but maybe using a View Transformer instead of a Model Transformer will help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my current solution is to have two fields for the icon in my entity

```
/**
 * @Constraints\Image(
 *      maxWidth = 40,
 *      maxHeight = 40,
 *      allowSquare = true,
 *      mimeTypes = "image/png",
 * )
 */
private $iconFile = null;

/**
 * Base64 of the icon in color version
 *
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="icon_color", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $icon = null;
```

(with the appropriate getter and setter)

then to have my data transformer for the WHOLE class  Category

```
class FileToBase64Transformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Transforms an object (file) to a base64.
     *
     * @param  $file
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($channel)
    {
        return $channel;
    }

    /**
     * reverse transforms
     *
     */
    public function reverseTransform($categoryl)
    {
        $iconFile = $category->getIconFile();
        if (!is_null($iconFile)) {
            $channel->setIcon(
                base64_encode(file_get_contents($iconFile))
            );
        }
        return $channel;
    }
}
```

and then in my CategoryType to associate the data transformer to the whole channel

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $transformer = new FileToBase64Transformer();

    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('theme_color')
        ->add('type')
        ->add('iconFile')
        ->addModelTransformer($transformer)
    ;
}
```

the validation still happen after the data transform, but now it's no more a problem , as the entity will not be persisted if the form is not valid